# how to know list of file types under Directories & Sub-directories

Tags: linux, filenames, recursive

Under CentOS, how to know file types under directories & sub-directories in one command?

Output should look like:

```
.inc, .inp, .odb, .a3db, .......
```

Comment: That is not filetype it is just part of the filename. Microsoft use this as a filetype, but it is not. Use `file` to find out what it really is.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/537980

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of unique filename extensions (these do *not* indicate "file type" on Unix), you may do

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "%s\n" "${pathname##*.}"
    done' sh {} + | sort -u
```

This will look for all regular files in or below the current directory whose names include at least one dot.  For these pathnames, a short script is executed that simply strips off everything up to and including the last dot and prints the remaining string.  `sort -u` then sorts these while deleting duplicates.

This assumes that the filename extension does not include a newline character.

To get this into a comma-separated list on a single line, pipe the output through `tr '\n' ','` (there will be a comma at the end of the line instead of a newline character if you do this).

If you want to include the dot in the output, then change the `printf` format string from `%s\n` to `.%s\n`.

---

Unix does have file types, such as regular files, directories, named pipes, character and block special files etc. But these are not distinguished by their filenames.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -U ext
ext=(**/?*.*(ND:e))
print -r -- ${(j:, :)ext}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return list of all file extentions in all directories and subdirectories.

- `find` command to find all files in directory and subdirectory, then `grep` for files with dot in their filename
- print the extensions of all files , by using `awk` having `.` (dot) as seperator and printing last field ( `$NF` )
- Then finally using `sort` and `uniq` to print only uniq extensions

> ```
> find <DIRECTORY_NAME> -type f -printf "%f\n"   | grep '\.' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq
> ```